# unable to get jquery to work

Tags: jquery, drupal

I'm constantly failing to do something useful with jquery. I'm using the Drupal CMS which integrates jquery by default. I can see the Drupal code calling jquery which works fine. I can also click on

```
<script src="http://samson:90/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4" type="text/javascript">
```

in Firebug, which shows the jquery code. I take this as a "jquery gets loaded and executed".

My code is linked with this code

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://samson:90/sites/all/modules/vimgalign/vimgalign.js?ll6x5c"></script>
```

and looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hallo = $("img");
})
```

I'm also shure that my code is loaded after jquery.js is loaded.

I do get the following error message: "$ is not a function". If I replace $ with jQuery I don't get an error message. But a breakpoint at

```
var hallo = $("img");
```

get's never hit.

Using the code rom sv_in works. But why can't I just call jQuery the standard way?

You can reach the page at http://samson.pluess-production.ch/node/19.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function($){
  var hallo = $('img');
  // Put the jquery code here. You can use $.
})(jQuery)
```

If this doesn't work then we would need to see your page.

Comment: Basically what `(function($) { .. } )(jQuery);`  is doing is: executing an anonymous function, the `()(jQuery)`, passing it the `jQuery` object as an argument, to `function($) {...}`, turning `$` into a `jQuery` shortcut. **GOOD PRACTICE**

Comment: Actually this is the only correct answer. After digging through the Drupal 7 documentation I learned, that the standard $(document).ready(function() ... call is not supported by the Drupal 7 installation. see http://drupal.org/node/756722

Answer (score 0):

Use tab "Net" in firebug, there you will see what really loaded and what did not. For me, http://samson:90 is not accessible.

Comment: I guess 'samson:90' resides in his computer like 'localhost' coz it is not having an extension like '.com', '.net'

Comment: Correct, samson:90 is a VM on my PC not accessible for others.